# Depend on other files from Jenkins job dsl script

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I have some large bash scripts in my job dsl files that I am declaring as

```
String script = '''
  # large script
'''
```

and calling it from the `shell` method

```
shell(script)
```

How ever, I would like to break out the scripts into shell files. I tried declaring

```
String script = new File('script.sh').text
```

But the job that executes the jenkins job dsl script does not appear to find the file, in fact I am not sure which location it is even executing from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [readFileFromWorkspace](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.readFileFromWorkspace) to read the contents of a file from a job workspace.

The path is specified relative to the workspace root.

The second example on the linked API docs above is for a batch file, but replace batch with shell and you have the solution for your case.

```
def runScript = readFileFromWorkspace('script.sh')
job('example-2') {
    steps {
        shell(runScript)
    }
}
```